# Calculate cofactor-matrix efficiently

Tags: matrix

I've implemented an algorithm that can calculate the cofactor-matrix of a matrix in $\mathcal{O}(n^5)$.

The algorithm just step-by-step iterates over the whole matrix ($\mathcal{O}(n^2)$) and for every $(i,j)$ in the matrix, it then calculates the determinant of the "sub-matrix" (leaving off row $i$ and column $j$) by using the [bareiss algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bareiss_algorithm) in $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Computing determinants of anything is so vastly expensive that it is almost always a good question to ask what you actually need it for, and whether what you want to do could not also be done without actually computing determinants.

Comment: Your are working on integers, do I understand correctly? And you need an exact integer answer even if it is going to be astronomically huge?

Comment: No, I am working with vector<vector<double>> in C++.

Comment: @chrysaetos99 then I would suggest switching to proper structures for matrices (raw double*, wrappers, external libraries), as while keeping the same asymptotic complexity, you will get the results much faster. Not sure it is your goal, though.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that this question still does not have a satisfying answer. The most interesting case is the one when the matrix is singular or almost singular, and in this case using the formula $\det(A) A^{-T}$ is either outright impossible, or otherwise it probably still is a bad idea in terms of stability. It looks like there should be an $O(n^3)$ solution even for this case.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni For an almost singular matrix $A$ still SVD might work well, but for an exact singular matrix with $\mathrm{det}(A) = 0$, co-factor can't be defined uniquely. We know that: $$A\mathbf{C}^{T} = \mathrm{det}(A) I$$, if $\mathrm{det}(A) = 0$ the equation $$A X = 0$$, where $X = \mathbf{C}^{T}$ has many non-trivial solutions. So, which one might be picked as co-factor?

Comment: @AloneProgrammer The cofactor matrix is well defined even for singular matrices. Its [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Inverse_of_a_matrix) is not $\det(A) A^{-1}$, that is just a characterization that works for invertible matrices. It is defined in terms of minor determinants.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I know but in that case for an exactly singular matrix, you won't get better than $\mathcal{O}(n^{5})$ by going through all the first minors and compute their determinants and I don't think there might be any better way to do it practically. Of course there are some much more complex algorithms to compute determinant somewhere between $\mathcal{O}(n^{2})$ and $\mathcal{O}(n^{3})$ such as Strassen or Coppersmith-Winograd algorithms, but those algorithms might not be easy to implement or available in common linear algebra libraries.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer *You won't get better than $\mathcal O(n^5)$* [citation needed]. Personally I would be surprised if there isn't a reasonably simple $\mathcal O(n^3)$ algorithm.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Found it on another answer on this website! [Fast algorithm for computing cofactor matrix](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/33028/fast-algorithm-for-computing-cofactor-matrix) Voting to close this as a duplicate. Note that Anton Menshov's solution is $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use SVD (singular value decomposition) instead of calculating inverse and determinant directly. SVD is still $\mathcal{O}(n^{3})$ in time complexity, but I think is much more stable. For singular decomposition of $A$ you have:

$$A = U \Sigma V^{T}$$

Where $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices and $\Sigma$ is just a diagonal matrix. So:

$$|\mathrm{det}(A)| = \prod_{i} \mathrm{diag}(\Sigma)_{i}$$

Please pay attention to the abs in the above formula, cause the only thing that we know is $\mathrm{det}(U),\mathrm{det}(V) = \pm 1$. Also, an inverse could be calculated from SVD as because $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices:

$$A^{-1} = V \Sigma^{-1} U^{T}$$

So the co-factor is:

$$\mathbf{C} = \mathrm{det}(A) A^{-T}$$

Comment: I know that A^T is the transposed matrix, but what is meant by A^(-T)? Is it the transposed of the inverse? This also doesn't work, if det(A) = 0, right?

Comment: @chrysaetos99 $A^{-T} = (A^{-1})^T$ of course a matrix with zero determinant does not have co-factor.

Answer (score 1):

Determinants and matrix inversion are pretty numerically unstable, but if all you are going for is speed, you can compute $A^{-1}$ in $O(n^3)$ time, then we have the cofactor matrix given by
$$
C = \mathrm{det}(A)(A^{-1})^T
$$

Comment: And how do you get $\mathrm{det}(A)$? Even calculating the inverse of matrix is really bad idea.